# Silverlight DoubleAnimation: Set KeyProperties from Codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, storyboard

Hi I define my Storyboard as Resource in XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="vor">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="master">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="point" KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="700"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and now I try to modify the Value from one of the EasingDoubleKeyFrames:

```
    private void test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        point.SetValue(EasingDoubleKeyFrame.ValueProperty, 400);
        vor.Begin();
    }
```

it doesn't work. You know why not?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: the storyboard doesn't start when i set the new valueproperty. without the new ValueProperty it works fine